# How to enable logging in published asp.net Core projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2

I published my asp.net core web api in a iis serveur ,  when i test in the browser  the application i get an 502.5 error.

i searched on how to find a solution , i found that i need to enable logging by changing the **stdoutLogEnabled="false"** to true.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
       <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="true">
       <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WsAZProjet.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: baf7ef69-c0ff-4e36-b69c-71ad3fd869b9-->
```

i changed that in iis serveur and retested the app in the browser but i didn't get the log directory generated , so i think  i should configure that  in code and then republish the app ?

do you have an idea on how to enable logging for published apps ?
should i restart iis for that to work ?

## Update

After searching , i found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0#troubleshoot-on-iis) that i need to manualy create the ***logs*** folder , i did that  and  tested again the app , i get a *log_stdout* file under the folder but it is empty !!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , [here](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) the reason of the error :

**Incorrect proecessPath, missing PATH variable, or dotnet.exe access violation**

> Browser: HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Application Log: Failed to start process with commandline ‘“dotnet” .\my_application.dll’ (portable app) or ‘”.\my_application_Foo.exe”’ (self-contained app), ErrorCode = ‘0x80070002’.
>
> ASP.NET Core Module Log: Log file created but empty
>
> Troubleshooting:
>     Check the processPath attribute on the  element in web.config to confirm that it is dotnet for a portable application or .\my_application.exe for a self-contained application.
>   For a portable application, dotnet.exe might not be accessible via the PATH settings. Confirm that C:\Program Files\dotnet\ exists in the System PATH settings.
>   For a portable application, dotnet.exe might not be accessible for the user identity of the Application Pool. Confirm that the AppPool user identity has access to the C:\Program Files\dotnet directory.

my processPath was set by me yesterday to *C://ProgramFiles/dotnet.exe* , changing that to just *dotnet* solve the issue and i get my log file informations now.